# PHP/CSS - Position your data according to their status

Tags: php, html, css

I am displaying order numbers and their status from a mssql database

The problem is that they don't stay next to each other but go straight down.

I would like to make 3 columns on my page with all the orders scrolling and stuck to their order numbers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/agrah.css">
    <title>AGRAH</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="col">
     <?php
            //CONNEXION ODBC SERVER//
            $dsn="";
            $user="";
            $password="";
            $conn=odbc_connect($dsn
                ,$user, $password);

            //REQUETES
            $sql = <<<EOF
                    SELECT [enc_cmd_num]
                    FROM [encaissement]
                    WHERE enc_date= '20221130'
                    EOF;

            $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
            

            while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)){ 
                echo $resultrow["enc_cmd_num"]."<br/>" ; }

                ?>

                <li>

                    <?php
            //CONNEXION ODBC SERVER//
            $dsn="Zeshop";
            $user="sa";
            $password="mrsushi";
            $conn=odbc_connect($dsn,$user, $password);

            //REQUETES
            $sql = <<<EOF
                    SELECT [enc_prepared]
                    FROM [encaissement]
                    WHERE enc_date= '20221130'
                    EOF;

            $results = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

            //CONDITION

                while($resultrow = odbc_fetch_array($results)) {
                    switch($resultrow['enc_prepared']){
                    case 0:
                        echo "<li><span>Commande en attente</span> \r\n";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        echo "<span>Commande en cours de préparation<br/></span></li>\r\n";
                        break;
                    default: echo "<td>Unknown</td>";
                }

            }

?>

</ul>
```

[image: RESULT]

Thanks to all for your precious help

Comment: why do you have multiple database connections?

Comment: For nothing, I deleted it

Comment: It appears that the code above is supposed to render content within a `ul` element yet you have `echo "<td>Unknown</td>";` which would be invalid markup

Comment: Because I asked several people but they told me to use <ul> and <li> tags to be able to organize the orders and their numbers side by side

Comment: It looks like you should be able to use a single sql query to return all the fields you want  rather than having nested a query inside a loop. I can see no issue then with printing out the required data within individual `li` elements ( which would be correct inside the `ul` parent element )

Comment: I did not understand what your explanation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the above 2 sql queries where they both return just a single field it seems likely that you could run a single SQL query that returns both columns in the recordset and iterate through that recordset just once. I cannot be certain but I believe the following ought to work

```
<?php
    $dsn="";
    $user="";
    $password="";
    $conn=odbc_connect( $dsn ,$user, $password );
    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/agrah.css" />
        
        <title>AGRAH</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="col">
        <?php
            # combine the two queries in single query with two columns
            $sql = "SELECT [enc_cmd_num],[enc_prepared]
                FROM [encaissement]
                WHERE enc_date= '20221130'";
                
            # run the query
            $results = odbc_exec( $conn, $sql );
            
            # iterate through the recordset once
            while( $row = odbc_fetch_array( $results ) ){
            
                # fork the output based upon value of this column
                switch( $row['enc_prepared'] ){
                    case 0: $prep='<span>Commande en attente</span>'; break;
                    case 1: $prep='<span>Commande en cours de préparation</span>'; break;
                    default:$prep='unknown';break;
                }
                
                # print the `li` with content from db and calculated data from above
                printf('<li>%s - %s</li>', $row["enc_cmd_num"], $prep );
            }


        ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are a genius, I would like to succeed like you!

Is it possible that the commands are displayed on the side when they reach the page pie?

Comment: `"You are a genius"` - very kind but probably incorrect, `"Is it possible that the commands are displayed on the side when they reach the page pie?"` - I have no idea what this means I am afraid to say.... can you clarify?

Comment: that the commands are displayed in a 3-column format and that they are not displayed until the footer

Comment: a `ul` element seems like the wrong HTML element to use if you want to display a 3 column layout. To do that suggests a `table` would be a better option but it is unclear what the content would be as you only have 2 database columns

Comment: It is simply that the data that are displayed are scattered on the page 
For example we divide the page in 3 and the data are displayed in the 3 columns so that they always remain on the page and they do not go down in footer :)

Comment: You could use CSS to govern the absolute dimensions of the UL and then use [columns layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) to ensure the elements flow as you expect

Comment: I can't thank you enough for what you've done for me, thank you for making everything work perfectly!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck and bonne année 2023